# Popup on form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, popup, submit

I would like to display a popup when someone successfully signs up for one of my websites. There data is writing to an external database (this works correctly) so I am a bit unsure as to which parts of code I can change and which need to remain. If any of you are able to advise on this that would be great! A bit of a noob when it comes to javascript!

Thanks in advance

```
<form name="signup" id="signup" action="http://creationonline.co.uk/signup.ashx" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_signup(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="addressbookid" value="1232079">
<!-- UserID - required field, do not remove -->
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="81918">
<!-- ReturnURL - when the user hits submit, they'll get sent here -->
<input type="hidden" name="ReturnURL" value="">
<!-- Email - the user's email address -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td> Sign up
</td><td><input name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" size="29"></td>
<td align="left"><input type="Submit" name="Submit" class="su_btn" value=">"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>`


<!--
function validate_signup(frm) {
    var emailAddress = frm.Email.value;
    var errorString = '';
    if (emailAddress == '' || emailAddress.indexOf('@') == -1) {
        errorString = 'Please enter your email address';
    }


var els = frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
{
    if (els[i].className == 'text' || els[i].className == 'date' || els[i].className == 'number')
    {
        if (els[i].value == '')
            errorString = 'Please complete all required fields.';
    }
    else if (els[i].className == 'radio')
    {
        var toCheck = document.getElementsByName(els[i].name);
        var radioChecked = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < toCheck.length; j++)
        {
            if (toCheck[j].name == els[i].name && toCheck[j].checked)
                radioChecked = true;
        }
        if (!radioChecked)
            errorString = 'Please complete all required fields.';
    }
}



    var isError = false;
    if (errorString.length > 0)
        isError = true;

    if (isError)
        alert(errorString);
    return !isError;
}


//-->
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if i understand you question, but u can remove all javascript from this code and it 'll stil work fine.

All grey part see here on stackoverflow, you can remove.

To do a popupm u'll need change your action to return something, and you'll need yo use ajax to get this return and send popup without reload the page.

I recomend use jquery ajax, it's a little bit easier.

See more on: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And to pop up you can use simple alert function or use jquery ui to get more beauty function http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I'd have thought the Javascript was the essential part? This is what is checking to see if the email address entered is valid and is bringing up the pop up to ask the user to enter a valid email address if that have not done so - at least that was my understanding??

What I am after is a way of bringing up a pop up (instead of diverting to another page) with a success message when the users successfully subscribes